# Content goes to the top when building on iOS (Cordova)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, statusbar

The problem is this: when building a project on . iPhone 12 and up. The upper part of the content "climbs" on the status bar.

Added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Plugins:

cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova-plugin-statusbar

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZrZ5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After install cordova-plugin-statusbar try to add following line in config.xml file

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, do not tell me yet how you can limit the scrolling of the content to the bar status.

When scrolling up the page, the content does not end before the bar status, but rather goes beyond it